# Retrieving a cropped photo from the Facebook Graph API

Tags: ios, database, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have developed a part of an iOS application that involves using Facebook's Graph API that accesses a user's photos, and allows the user to crop that image into a square with a desired zoom. The images must be squares. Is there a way to use the Graph API with a given rect parameter so it returns a URL of the desired photo cropped into that rect? I have done some research and it seems like there isn't, but I was hoping for another set of eyes on that.

Assuming that there isn't, what sounds like a better idea:

1. Uploading the cropped photo to my own servers for future access.

or

2. Use my own SQL database to store the rect of the cropping and the URL of the photo (hosted by facebook), and then load the full facebook photo and crop it to how I want.

1 offers efficiency when loading data from the internet, but it means storing more data in my own servers (this could get expensive in the future)

2 means I will use less space on my own servers, but also means that the entire photo will be forced to be loaded, even parts that won't be used.

I'm leaning towards 2, but I don't deal too much with web/database work so I was hoping for some advice. Thanks.

Comment: You should not store Facebook CDN URLs for long-time use, as they can change at any time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook already does some transformations of the pictures. It is not exactly what you want but might be interesting to take a look:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/platform-image-source/

@CBroe has a good point not to store the urls obtained from Facebook directly. I would try and save the cropped picture on your servers.